# What invention or condition made it possible for mRNA vaccines to work for COVID-19?

Tags: covid-19

mRNA vaccines have been developed for [over 30 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA_vaccine). What invention or condition made it possible for mRNA vaccines to work for COVID-19, despite the fact that they haven't been successful yet for other diseases?

---

My research so far: I've watched/read the following resources on mRNA vaccines, but couldn't find the answer yet:

- https://youtu.be/oMXGGmBfkf8 (3 min)
- https://youtu.be/XTLYXmgG8DU (5 min)
- https://youtu.be/-92HQA0GcI8 (10 min)
- https://www.health.harvard.edu/blog/why-are-mrna-vaccines-so-exciting-2020121021599
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA_vaccine

I've also unsuccessfully Googled "What invention or condition made it possible for mRNA vaccines to work for COVID-19?".

Comment: Have you looked at StackExchange? Including Bio.SE?

Comment: Have you checked Wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RNA_vaccine#History or the refs in that section e.g. https://www.statnews.com/2020/11/10/the-story-of-mrna-how-a-once-dismissed-idea-became-a-leading-technology-in-the-covid-vaccine-race/